# MavenProject injection does not seem to work

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I try to write my own maven plugin, and I try to access the MavenProject with the usual annotation. However, when I execute the plugin the project field does not get injected and remains null. 
Here is my example code:

```
package xyz;

import org.apache.maven.plugin.*;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.*;
import org.apache.maven.project.*;

/**
 * @goal develop
 *
 */
public class Experiment extends AbstractMojo {

    @Parameter( defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true, required = true )
    protected MavenProject project;

    @Override
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
        if (project == null) {
            getLog().error("Variable ${project} is null!");
        } else {
            getLog().info("Variable ${project} is filled!");
        }
    }
}
```

Whatever I try, I can't get it to work that maven automatically injects the project field with the proper object, I always get the information that the field is null. Any idea what I do wrong?

The pom file doesn't seem to be the interesting part here, because I get this behaviour with big poms I use for ages in my builds.
But I can reproduce it even with the most simple possible pom file:

```
 <project>
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
   <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
   <version>1</version>
 </project>
```

Comment: Show your full pom file!

Comment: The most simple sample pom file will do, see edit.

Comment: What is the most simple sample pom file? I don't have one...you must have one so why not posting it here.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone drops onto this question: I had the same problem, the MavenProject was not injected with the annotaded property like this:

```
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", required = true, readonly = true)
private MavenProject project;
```

I had - guided by obviously pre-annotation mojo samples - defined the goal name with a Javadoc tag @goal as follows:

```
/**
 * execute my goal
 * @goal mygoal
 */
public class MyGoal extends AbstractMojo {
   // goal's code goes here
}
```

It all worked after changing this to using an annotation for the mojo class as follows:

```
@Mojo(name = "mygoal")
public class MyGoal extends AbstractMojo {
   // goal's code goes here
}
```

It seems to me as if maven only looks at annotations if the mojo is specified as an annotation. Mixing anotations (for fields) with Javadoc tags does not seem to work correctly (although I have not investigated this any further).

Comment: There are two ways to inject value in a field from POM: 
**Plugin Tools Javadoc Tags** and **Plugin Tools Java Annotation**

Below is sample of Plugin Tools Javadoc Tag:
/**
 * @goal develop
 */
And below is sample of Plugin Tools Java Annotation:
 @Parameter( defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true, required = true ). Check the follwing comment:

Comment: From [Maven documentation] (https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-plugin/examples/using-annotations.html) : "Since version 3.0 of the maven-plugin-plugin, you can use Java5 annotations to generate the plugin descriptor file."
Remember to check POM configuration in the earlier link: To be able to use these Java annotations, you need to add configuration to your plugin POM

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no `pom.xml` of the `maven-plugin` project, try as following:

the `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>stackoverflow.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>31111852</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>mojo-parent</artifactId>
        <version>34</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                <artifactId>plexus-component-metadata</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate-metadata</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The `stackoveflow.Experiment.java` file

```
package stackoveflow;

import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Mojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Parameter;
import org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject;

@Mojo(name = "develop")
public class Experiment extends AbstractMojo {

    @Parameter( property ="project", defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true, required = true )
    protected MavenProject project;


    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
        if (project == null) {
            getLog().error("Variable ${project} is null!");
        } else {
            getLog().info("Variable ${project} is filled!");
        }
    }
}
```

install it locally with `maven clean install`,

and after that run it by `mvn stackoverflow.maven:31111852:develop`

Comment: Is it intended that you set `property ="project"`, but also changed the variable name from `project` to `mavenProject`? In any case, nothing helps ;-)

Comment: Just copied the code from my Mojo that works. Now copied your code with additions of annotations Mojo, and component. try it now

Comment: I can't set the `@Component` annotation, as it complains that it is not valid at this location, and the `@Mojo` annotation doesn't seem to work (this may be due to different versions of plugin dependencies or versions of maven).
However, it seems to me that the syntax of the mojo is correct (because it's done that way everywhere I look for how defining mojos). I suppose that there is wrong something else, but I have no idea what could induce this behaviour. Even stranger as all other plugins work as desired (maven-dependency-plugin also uses this project variable, and there is no problem).

Comment: pay attention that the  `Component` annotation coming from `org.codehaus.plexus.component.annotations.Component`

Comment: `@Component` is not valid for a plugin itself. Removed the `@Component` from your Experiment class. See here: [Maven Plugin Tools](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-annotations/index.html).

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for your comment. removed the `@Component`, installed and ran it. works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

The parameter injection should look like this:

```java
@Parameter( defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true, required = true )
private MavenProject project;
```

If you have a parameter like readonly/required etc. giving a property does not make sense. Property means you could change it via system properties like this:

```
mvn -DpropName=value ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To use Java5 annotations you need to switch on annotation processing so that your goals are included in the META-INF/maven/plugin.xml file built inside your jar.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-descriptor</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

See https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-plugin/examples/using-annotations.html